# Generate pkg-config out of Makefile

Tags: makefile, pkg-config

For a project, which historically uses *make* I would now like to generate a *pkg-config* file. However I cannot seem to prevent the substitution of the variables

```
mylib.pc:
    echo 'prefix='$(PREFIX) > bzip2.pc
    echo "exec_prefix=\${prefix}" >> mylib.pc
    echo 'libdir=\${prefix}/lib'  >> mylib.pc

install: mylib.pc
```

Afterwards I have a `mylib.pc` with expanded variables, which is not what I want.
So how does one generate a *pkg-config* out of a *Makefile* or how do I prevent variable substitution?

Comment: What do you want `bzip2.pc` and `mylib.pc` to contain, after you execute this rule? (Don't *describe* the new text, *show* it to us.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will produce what I think you want:

```
mylib.pc:
    echo 'prefix='$(PREFIX)                                                    
    echo 'exec_prefix=$${prefix}' >> mylib.pc
    echo 'libdir=$${prefix}/lib' >> mylib.pc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `define` to define a variable while keeping new lines and use `file` to write a file.

```
define PKG_CONFIG_TEMPLATE
prefix=$(PREFIX)
exec_prefix=$${prefix}
includedir=$${prefix}/include
libdir=$${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: MyLib
Description: MyLib description
Version: 1.0
Cflags: -I$${includedir}
Libs: -L$${libdir}
endef

mylib.pc:
    $(file > $@,$(PKG_CONFIG_TEMPLATE))
```